# JBoss Seam only allow Parameters via POST

Tags: http, configuration, methods, jboss, jsf-1.2

I'm using JBoss 4.2 with Java Seam and in my application there is an login-form implemented.
Now if I submit the form in the GUI the Parameters will be sent via HTTP-POST, but if I try to send the Data via HTTP-GET it will be accepted too.

That should be prevented, but I didn't find out how. 
Could I set the Method in the pages.xml or do I need to find out programmatically if the Request is Post or Get.

Are there other ways to do that or how should I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the followin Statement in the web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Post Pages</web-resource-name>
        <description />
        <url-pattern>/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will only allow POST Request in the defined url.patterns